# How to get android device information without open app?

Tags: android

How to get **android device** information without open app. After application upgrade Google play store app display open button but I want to get user device for push notification without open application.

Push notification or any other background services is not implemented in last build.

Comment: Hi, You can use a onInstall(onPackageChange) broadcastreceiver. . .

Answer (score 0):

Divide the situation to two cases:

- New app:

There is no way to start your app without the user pressing it, the android system prevent it. Best thing is to put a BootReceiver and only when the user restarts the device you could register and stuf..

- Upgraded app:

Push should work with the same regiId, send a silent push to the device to "wake" him up and then do your thing without posting a notification to the user.

As for your situation: there is no other way then to create a new build and add a BootReceiver because you dont have any regId for the push yet. Good Luck